# Delete individual cookie on andriod phone?

Tags: browser

I have an android phone (Samsung s3 mini). Can I delete an individual cookie?

I can see how to delete all cookies, but this isn't what I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookies form the default android browser are stored in /data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db. The problem is that other applications, for security reasons, do not have access to this file.

Since the Browser application hasn't implement this functionality, it is not possible.